# CSS Content property not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a website where I'm trying to create link separators in my navigation bar using the CSS `:before` pseudoclass along with the `+` selector in this way:

`/* Targets list items with a list item before it, so that we don't put separators
before the first element, nor after the last element. */`

nav li + li:before{content:url('someimagehere.gif');}

If I don't use an image, and using a string such as "/", it works fine in IE (as well as Chrome, Firefox, etc.). However, it's with using an image that fails in IE alone (Chrome and Firefox works fine). Any idea's on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I just discovered that the above rule is being overridden in IE, but only in IE. All the other browsers seem to render it just fine, while IE refuses to do the same, even with an `!important` declaration.

Comment: ie9 or ie10? what is ur browser

Comment: I'm testing in IE9, and I'm using the dev tools to see how it'll render in IE8 and IE7.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the top of your html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

*Ref:*

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3525200/ie-content.png

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp